# Moving an object to follow the camera movement in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, camera, html5-video, augmented-reality

I want to place an object inside a video  feed and make that object steadyly follow the camera movements. An example would be to place a sofa (image) in your living room (live camera stream) and then move the camera around, but sofa being hooked to the place as it was placed orginally.

To do this I want to track the movements of video background and move the object propotionatly so that it create a perception that the object is attahed to the living room (augmented reality).

Is there any way of doing this in javascript? I want this to be compatible with iOS so webGL is not an option.

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://trackingjs.com/)?

Comment: Thanks Arik for the pointer, but it's to track the moving objects on the camera. But what I need is rather simple, just to trace the movement of camera itself (delta x,y,z) so that I can move the objects along with.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to overlay a 2D image of a sofa onto a fixed tracked point in the video, instead of a 3D sofa object in a 3d scene?